# Swift - status bar settings dont apply

Tags: swift

I want to change color of my status bar to white

i try this in appdelegate

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
```

and add key View controller-based status bar appearance with value of NO in plist

Also i set here [image]

and for experiment sake try to hide it here

[image]

It neither not hides not changing color.

Where can be the problem ?

Comment: Can you change the color overriding the prefersStatusBarHidden method?

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. Check once more next moments:

1. in Info.plist:

   - View controller-based status bar appearance: NO
   - Status bar style: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent (if you need to start **light** style)
2. In code. Relative to what you need, you can customize status bar.

   - UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

Comment: everything matches. but it is black :(

Comment: Make from scratch new project, and provide this details.
Result?

Comment: same result in blank project

Comment: XCode version?
Publish project on GitHub, I would check

Comment: @AlexeyK, there is no settings in Info.plist. I've written there, and status bar become with light content. Why didn't you setup as I've described?

Comment: it seems that I edited wrong plist. sorry for that and thanks for help!